# Adding a jsonString to Alamofire request

Tags: swift, web-services, alamofire

im trying to use the alamofire library but i have a problem, i am trying to add the next jsonString to the body of the request an it allways gives me the same  400 status code, can someone help me please, this is the string and my code:

Json String: {"moment":{"name" : "hola","begin" : "12-5-2005 0:0","end" : "22-4-2007 0:0","stored" : false}}

and this is my actual code, thanks

```
                let jsonString = "{\"moment\":{" + "\"name\" : " + "\"" + nombre + "\"" + ",\"begin\" : \"" + fechaIni + "\"," +
                    "\"end\" : " + "\"" + fechaFin  + "\"" + "," + "\"stored\" : false" + "}" + "}"

                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://whatmatters.deploy-cd.com/api/me/moments.json")!)
                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "ContentType")
                request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
                Alamofire.request(request).authenticate(user: user, password: pass)
                    .response { resp in
                        print(resp)

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
you have to serialise your data in json

here how should be look like :

```
let jsonString = "{\"moment\":{" + "\"name\" : " + "\"" + nombre + "\"" + ",\"begin\" : \"" + fechaIni + "\"," +
                "\"end\" : " + "\"" + fechaFin  + "\"" + "," + "\"stored\" : false" + "}" + "}"

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://whatmatters.deploy-cd.com/api/me/moments.json")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "ContentType")
            let stringData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
            do {
        let jsonData:NSData? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(stringData!, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSData
        request.HTTPBody = jsonData
    } catch let caught as NSError {
        print(caught)
    }
            Alamofire.request(request).authenticate(user: user, password: pass)
                .response { resp in
                    print(resp)

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Way I do it to send json Post parameters, is to put the parameter in a `Dictionary` like this:

```
let parameters  = [
                "moment" : [
                    "name"  : nombre,
                    "begin" : fechaIni,
                    "end"   : fechaFin,
                    "stored"   : false,

                ]]
```

So all the code will be like this

```
 var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://whatmatters.deploy-cd.com/api/me/moments.json")!)
 request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
 request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "ContentType")
 // request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
 let parameters = [
                "moment" : [
                    "name"  : nombre,
                    "begin" : fechaIni,
                    "end"   : fechaFin,
                    "stored"   : false,

                ]]

request =  Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(request, parameters: parameters).0
Alamofire.request(request).authenticate(user: user, password: pass)
                .response { resp in
                    print(resp)
            }
```

**Note:** please mind the dictionary values data types and the data types required in you json, i.e If you need all the json Values a `String` please cast the dictionary values to be `String`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dictionary instead of a the string, a short and simple solution can be found in the Alamofire doc:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#post-request-with-json-encoded-parameters

```
let parameters = [
    "foo": [1,2,3],
    "bar": [
        "baz": "qux"
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
// HTTP body: {"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": {"baz": "qux"}}
```